# How to calculate the time complexity?

Tags: time-complexity

Assume that function f is in the complexity class O(N (log N)<sup>2</sup>), and that for N = 1,000 the program runs in 8 seconds.
How to write a formula T(N) that can compute the approximate time that it takes to run f for any input of size N???

Here is the answer:

```
8 = c (1000 x 10)
c = 8x10^-4 
T(N) = 8x10-4* (N log2 N)
```

I don't understand the first line where does the 10 come from?
Can anybody explain the answer to me please? Thanks!

Comment: I guess it a mistake: (log1000)^2 = 9 => 8 = c (1000 x 9)

Comment: How did you arrive at the 'answer' ?

Comment: Oh. The answer might be incorrect. sorry..

Comment: This seems like a question for a high school algebra class, not a programming question.

Comment: just wanted to add that that's not how complexity functions work.. there's also an unwritten O(1) constant that can be significant when your N is small, where 1000 is still small. I don't remember the last time someone tried to get a T(N) equation

Comment: Your teacher can explain it to you; that's what they get paid to do.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand the first line where does the 10 come from? Can
>   anybody explain the answer to me please? Thanks!

T(N) is the maximum time complexity.  `c` is the constant or `O(1)` time, which is the portion of the algorithm's speed which is not affected by the size of the input. The `10` comes from rounding to simplify the math. It's actually `9.965784`, which is `log2` of `1000`, e.g.

`N x log2 N` is
`1000 x 10` or 
`1000 x 9.965784`

Comment: Is that supposed to be 1000 * 10^2 ?

Answer (score 0):

O(N (log N)^2) describes how the runtime scales with N, but it's not a formula for calculating runtime in seconds. In fact, Big-O notation doesn't generally give the exact scaling function itself, but an upper bound on it as N becomes large. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) (there's a nice picture showing this last point).

If you're interested in a function's runtime in practice (particularly in the non-asymptotic regime, i.e. small N), one option is to actually run the function and measure it. Do this for multiple values of N, chosen on some grid (possibly with nonlinear spacing). Then, you can interpolate between these points.

Answer (score 0):

Define `S(N)=N(log N)^2`

If you can assume that S(N) bounds your program for all N >= 1000

Then you can bound your execution time by good'ol rule of three:

```
S(1000) -  T(1000)
S(N)    -  T(N)

T(N) <= S(N)* T(1000)/S(1000) for all N >=1000

S(1000) approx 10E4
T(1000) = 8

T(N) <= N(log N)^2 * 8 / 10E4
```